# Publish own work online, ethics and platform

Tags: publications, online-resource, online-publication, academic-freedom

My question is similar to [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44055/publishing-vs-putting-work-online-under-a-free-license). If someone wants to publish his work in the medical field, for free but without a review process, how is this seen by the academic world? Are there any online services or platforms that provide this service? Is this usually seen as a problem by the institution in which one may work?

Comment: Look up all the referring to arxiv.org on this site - it is a major platform for this type of services. The answers to these other questions also mostly answer your question.

Comment: I see arxiv is based on non health related science, i'm editing my question, thanks for the hint

Comment: In general, academic research that isn't peer reviewed gets far less attention than research that is.  Also, for the medical field in particular, I would wonder about ethical oversight.  You generally can't publish in a peer-reviewed journal unless your research was conducted with the oversight of some sort of independent ethics board; if your work didn't have that kind of oversight, it's probably going to be impossible for anyone to make use of it.

Comment: Why do you want to publish specifically *without* peer review? It might help people answer your question if they understood more about what you are actually looking for.

Comment: For example: If you want to publish without peer review, you could just keep a blog and publish whatever you want on it. Does that suit your needs? If not, why not?

Comment: I was inspired by a discussion in researchgate (i can't find it now) were they talked about an hypothetic method of publication which was uncontrolled by the big literature firm. Also now the publication of a paper is very delayed in time and there's also publication bias. By publishing it in a platform you could partially avoid these problems and also get a feedback from other experts in the field which is a sort of "peer-review" to assess the validity of a study. A blog is something too much decentralized in my opinion for this kind of work. I hope my comment is clear!

Answer (score 3):

> how is this seen by the academic world?

Generally speaking, as inferior to a peer-reviewed paper. But the 'academic world' is made up of a lot of different people. Assuming you have conducted a high-quality study, the extent to which a reader would consider your findings valid or robust or believable really depends on how they feel about the value added by peer-review. Given the growing evidence of the inadequacy of peer-review, the academic world may increasingly see this type of publication as acceptable. But I would suggest that we are not there yet. A more important question for the context of medical research might relate to how the clinical world would see it.

> Are there any online services or platforms that provide this service?

Yes. For example, [PeerJ Preprints](https://peerj.com/preprints/).

> Is this usually seen as a problem by the institution in which one may
>   work?

In terms of medical research I would say it definitely would be seen as a problem if used as an alternative (rather than a complement) to publication in a peer-reviewed journal. At an absolute minimum, your institution would probably expect your research output to be indexed by PubMed. If, however, you use the preprint route as a complement to publication in a peer-reviewed journal then it should not be seen as a problem in itself. It could become a problem if your target journal does not accept papers previously published an another form.